RefreshBean vs Pod rollout for using new secrets generated by Hashicorp Vault
I have a java microservice, and I would like to automatically rollout the credentials used by it to access other components like DBs, using Hashicorp Vault dynamic secret engins.
Lets say my app fetchs credentials to the DB from Vault at the startup of the pod, and Lets say I setup a TTL of 15min.
I was gonna go with a vault agent sidecar that will trigger a stop and start of my pod when the TTL is achieved. And kill the pod when max TTL is achieved.
Recently I learned that spring cloud has features like refreshing application configs live without restarting the application.
But this forces me to change my codebase to use spring vault.
If we use native application packages using frameworks like quarkus or spring graalvm support, we can boot start our application super quick, so I do not understand why go to the complexity of trying to reload the application configs without restarting it.
Knowing that killing pods regularly is considered a good security practice.
Please forgive my ignorance, I know that I am missing something here but just couldn't figure out what.

can you please precise the reason of the down vote so I can edit the question accordingly ?

How do you know when to restart the services or pods? Who or which mechanism is responsible to restart them? In the middle of huge traffic, the secret is changed/rotated. How do you deal with it? Answering these questions adds complexity to your design too. Therefore each scenario has its own design, its own pros and cons.

thanks for your answer. I edited my question to precise the senario I am working with.

In case of huge traffic, do you know if there is a benchmark done somewhere showing that refreshing beans is way faster than restarting a quarkus app that start in milliseconds, or at least can you confirm from your experience ?

I have had the experience with Kafka clients and certificates, and yes the in-app reload of certificates were much faster than restarting the whole pod.

How much time were your pods taking to restart ? were you using microservice frameworks like quarkus or micronaut ?
